# How can I select one row of data per hour?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new at sql.
There is something that makes me confused, i got data per minute, but i only need a row of it per hour or per 2 hours. For example when i select data from the previous day, it shows me 1440 rows and i need to reduce them to less rows to make some charts.
Thanks in advance.

when i use this query:

`select [Value],[Time] from [AbsoluteData] where [Sensor] = '5100' and  [Time] >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) AND[Time] < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`

i got:

[image]

Comment: "Here's a picture of my car.  Something's not working right.  Fix it."  *(Do not post images of code, it does not help us help you.  Post the actual code in your question.)* [Here's another good reference](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 2):

You can select on row per hour by using `row_number()` like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(datetimecol as date), datepart(hour, datetimecol)
                                order by datetimecol
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I cannot read your image and you don't have a sample query or sample data, so this uses generic names.

Answer (score 0):

If the data drops in every minute and you want just one within a given range (last hour or last day), just restrict the rows to the range and pick 1:

```
select top 1
       [Value], [Time]
  from [AbsoluteData]
 where [Sensor] = '5100'
   and cast(Time as date) = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)
 order by Time desc;
```

(last one yesterday)

or:

```
set rowcount 1;

select [Value], [Time]
  from [AbsoluteData]
 where [Sensor] = '5100'
   and cast(Time as date) = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)
 order by Time desc;

set rowcount 0;
```